# servlet getParts() in uploading file

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

I have implemented drag & drop file uploading in jsp and servlet, but I have a problem. Here is a part of my `upload.jsp` code:

```
   function dropUpload(event) {
        var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
        upload(files);
    }

    function upload(files) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        for (var i in files) {
            formData.append('file[]', files[i]);
         }

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        };
        xhr.open("POST", "UploadServlet"); 
        xhr.send(formData);
    }
```

I use the `getParts()` method in my `UploadServlet.java` code to get the files that the user uploads, like below:

```
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public UploadServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    String savePath = "D:\\TEST";
    // creates the save directory if it does not exists
    File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);
    if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
        fileSaveDir.mkdir();
    }
    response.getWriter().println(request.getParts().size());
    for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
        if(part.getContentType() == null) {
            continue;
        }
        response.getWriter().println("Part name: " + part.getName());
        response.getWriter().println("Size: " + part.getSize());
        response.getWriter().println("Content Type: " + part.getContentType());
        String fileName = extractFileName(part, response);
        response.getWriter().println(fileName);
        part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
        response.getWriter().println("already upload file:" + fileName);
        response.getWriter().println("=============================================");
    }

}

 private String extractFileName(Part part,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
        //response.getWriter().println(contentDisp);
        String[] items = contentDisp.split(";");
        for (String s : items) {
            if (s.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                return s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 2, s.length()-1);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

But I can't understand that if I upload 2 files with `upload.jsp`, 
the value of `getParts().size()` is 4; it means that I always have 2 more files than exactly what I upload, and the 2 external files name and contentType will be null, and it will cause an error in `part.write()`.

My solution is use the if statement

```
if(part.getContentType() == null) {
            continue; }
```

to ignore the null file.

Can somebody tell me why this happens?

Comment: what is header `"content-disposition"` for the parts which don't contain a `content-type` header?

Comment: and have you debugged your JS client to be sure that you really only add two files to the FormData? According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append you should also provide a third argument to `FormData.append`